# Get higest value of each relation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have Project table, ProjectDesign Table and Design Table

So each project have multiple Designs and they are related by ProjectDesign table

Like this

Project Table

```
+------------+----------+
| ProjectKey |   Name   |
+------------+----------+
|          1 | Project1 |
|          2 | Project2 |
|          3 | Project3 |
+------------+----------+
```

ProjectDesign Table

```
+------------+-----------+
| ProjectKey | DesignKey |
+------------+-----------+
|          1 |         1 |
|          2 |         2 |
|          3 |         3 |
|          1 |         4 |
|          1 |         5 |
+------------+-----------+
```

Design Table

```
+-----------+------+
| DesignKey | Name |
+-----------+------+
|         1 | Key1 |
|         2 | Key2 |
|         3 | Key3 |
|         4 | Key4 |
|         5 | Key5 |
+-----------+------+
```

That I want to do is to select MAX designKey of each project. I try as:

```
SELECT MAX([PD].[DesignKey])
FROM [Project] AS [p]
INNER JOIN [ProjectDesign] AS [PD] ON [PD].[ProjectKey] = [P].[ProjectKey]
INNER JOIN [Design] AS [D] ON [PD].[DesignKey] = [D].[DesignKey]
```

But it only gets one value, and its the highest design key, but I want highest design key of each project. How can I achieve that?

Comment: HINT:  See GROUP BY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
SELECT [p].ProjectKey, max([PD].[DesignKey])
FROM [Project] AS [p]
INNER JOIN [ProjectDesign] AS [PD] ON [PD].[ProjectKey] = [P].[ProjectKey]
INNER JOIN [Design] AS [D] ON [PD].[DesignKey] = [D].[DesignKey]
group by [p].ProjectKey;
```

Answer (score 1):

Only bridge table is enough for you to get this

```
SELECT ProjectKey, max(DesignKey)
From ProjectDesign
Group by ProjectKey
```

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GROUP BY or a Windowing function to do this -- here is how to do it with a windowing function:

```
SELECT MAX([PD].[DesignKey]) OVER (PARTITION BY PD.ProjectKey) AS MAX_BY_PROJECT
FROM [Project] AS [p]
INNER JOIN [ProjectDesign] AS [PD] ON [PD].[ProjectKey] = [P].[ProjectKey]
INNER JOIN [Design] AS [D] ON [PD].[DesignKey] = [D].[DesignKey]
```